# kineticjs canvas to image on local html page

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to generate an image of my kineticjs canvas in a similar fashion to how it is done in [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/). (Although unlike the example, my canvas does contain images from a local subdirectory.)

However, I am aware of the following:

> The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown.

However, I **require** to be able to generate the image on **local html page**. Is there anyway of working around the above security requirement either with `toDataURL` or any other image generation methods?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use any image you got from the web as a source for your Kinetic.Image.**

So you *can* display that image on your local html page.

What you *can't do* is then export that web page as an image with toDataURL.

You also can't examine the pixel array with context.getImageData.

If you are just drawing rects/circles/etc, but no external images, then you're good.

If you download a web image and save it on your local drive, that image is still "dirty" and will cause the security error--even though it is now on your local machine.

**Workarounds:**

*This sometimes works:*

Get an image from the web, modify it in Photoshop and save-as a new file *to the same directory as the kinetic .html file that will be using the file.*  This will often remove the "dirty" flag from the image.

Alternatively, you can install a web server on your local machine (no big deal these days).  I'm thinking IIS or WAMP.

If you're willing to avoid Internet Explorer, you can host your image on a site that allows cross-origin access to images.  One such hosting site is dropbox.com.  Then you can load your images with the crossOrigin flag set to "anonymous" and the resulting image will not be "dirty".

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload= ...
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.src="yourDropboxImage.png";
```

Comment: Its actually for an assignment so I have to send back a zip with a working demo so pushing to a server is not a possibility and putting the image in the same directory will ruin my directory hierarchy

Comment: Then if you're trying to `toDataURL` or `getImageData` a canvas containing a "dirty" flagged image, you're answer is...you can't.  See my edited answer for 1 more possibility if your demo-user will have access to the internet.